# Getting caller context info

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying out a JavaScript design pattern (not sure if there's a name for it?) where I have prototype functions as collection of items. To create a new item I first instantiate a collection, get the newItemBuilder function, sets whatever name or other attributes I want it to have and create the actual Item.

However, down in each Item, I want to retrieve the collectionId it belongs to without to much hustle. Is this possible in JavaScript/Node.js ? Can I get some kind of caller context info ?

I have created a Gist for full source here https://gist.github.com/Niklas9/6350880, or see the fractions below.

Fraction from Collection.js:

```
var Collection = function() {
    this.id = 23423;
    this.name = 'collection 1';
}
```

Fraction from Item.js:

```
var Item = function() {
    this.name = null;
    this.collectionId = null;
}
```

Fraction from ItemBuilder.js:

```
var ItemBuilder = function() {
    this.name = null;
}

ItemBuilder.prototype.withName = function(name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

ItemBuilder.prototype.create = function() {
    var item = Item;
    item.name = this.name;
    item.collectionId = null; // <-- this is where I want to get collectionId
    return item;
}
```

Fraction from caller:

```
var itemBuilder = collection.newItemBuilder();
var item = itemBuilder.withName('item 1').create();
```

Comment: `var item = new Item();` <-- this way you initialize a **new** object with those properties, otherwise you are setting them as properties of the `Item` function object